# Do not hard code jsp links inside servlet

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am learning JSP and Servlets. Consider the following code inside the `doPost` method of a `Servlet` which forwards a `HTTP request` to a `JSP` -

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/MyWebApp/MvcView.jsp");
```

I wonder what will happen if someone wants this servlet to forward the request to another jsp instead of the one above ? Does one have to change this code manually every time in their application ? How can one free oneself of all this manual work ?

Comment: Read it from properties file or construct page name with some request parameters.

Comment: @DanglingPiyush - Thanks. Can you give me some links with examples for that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple solution is to set the url as a parameter for your servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>YourServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.you.YourServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>url</param-name>
        <param-value>/MyWebApp/MvcView.jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

and the in the servlet:

```
public class YourServlet {

  protected String url = null;

  public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {
    this.url = servletConfig.getInitParameter("url");
  }

  public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(url);  

  }
}
```

then there is no need to recompile servlet code to chage the url.

Comment: Are there any other methods to do this ?